Why does it say that I have reached the max recursion depth? How can I fix it?
cities = ["Boston", "Las Vegas", "Porto Alegre", "Cape Town", "Berlin", "Okinawa", "Sydney"]
hotels = [255, 450, 150, 250, 650, 675, 850]
flights = [950, 3000, 4500, 2750, 2500, 3500, 10500]


def add_destination(city, hotel, flight):
    global cities, flights, hotels
    print("""Add your desired destination. Please include your hotel and flight cost,
    as well as the name of your desired location and hotel.""")
    new_place_city = input("Please type your new city: ")
    new_place_hotel = int(input("Please type your new hotel's price per night: "))
    new_place_flight = int(input("Please type the cost of your flight:"))
    cities.append(new_place_city)
    hotels.append(new_place_hotel)
    flights.append(new_place_flight)

    cost = [flights] + [hotels]

def calculate_total_cost(hotels, flights):
    global city, hotel, flight, cost
    f_cost = sum(flights)
    h_cost = sum(hotels)
    t_cost = sum({h_cost, f_cost})
    result = calculate_total_cost(hotels, flights)

   


def display_budget_summary(cities, hotels, flights):
    for i in range(len(cities)):
        print(f"{cities[i]}, ${hotels[i]} ${flights[i]}.")
    result = calculate_total_cost(hotels, flights)
    print(f"Your current budget/money spent is ${result}.")

while True:
    print(f"""Currently, the cities you plan to visit during your vacation are {cities}."
    Please choose an option to make any edits to your vacation.""")
    print("1. Add a destination")
    print("2. View budget summary")
    print("3. Exit program")

    option = int(input("Please choose an answer: "))

    if option == 1:
        add_destination(cities, hotels, flights)

    elif option == 2:
        display_budget_summary(cities, hotels, flights)

    elif option == 3:
        break

    else:
        print("Please choose a valid option.")

Provided above is my code. When I run this on Online Python, I receive the error message that I have reached the maximum recursion distance, and I am confused as to what I can due to fix this. From what I understand, most of the issues lie around the display function. Can anyone elaborate as to how I can fix this mistake?

Just so you know, code on SO should always represent a [mre]. Before posting a question, make sure to do some testing to isolate the problem - what's the smallest code sample that can recreate the issue?

Also, please post the full error if possible. You'll get better assistance. Thanks

You have infinite recursion in calculate_total_cost() Also, t_cost = sum({h_cost, f_cost}) is highly dubious. What if h_cost and f_cost are equal?

This function is the problem:
def calculate_total_cost(hotels, flights):
    global city, hotel, flight, cost
    f_cost = sum(flights)
    h_cost = sum(hotels)
    t_cost = sum({h_cost, f_cost})
    result = calculate_total_cost(hotels, flights)

The function calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself ... forever.
To fix it, you need to make the function not call itself.
Perhaps you meant to just return t_cost ?
In fact, I think the function could be reduced to this:
def calculate_total_cost(hotels, flights):
    return sum(flights) + sum(hotels)

It doesn't appear to need the global variables at all.  Why are they there?
